# How about the articles on Journal of Advances in Applied Mathematics?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Would like to know the quality of the articles on the Journal of Advances in Applied Mathematics.
Here is [the website](http://www.isaacpub.org/AboutThisJournal.aspx?ids=1&utm_source=lt&utm_campaign=papersubmission&utm_medium=jaam0801).

Answer (score 2):

Isaac Scientific Publishing is on [Beall's List](https://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/). So, it would seem that the outlook is not good and one should exercise caution.